# WPF HwndHost Drag & Drop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm not certain why, but the drag drop events on an HwndHost don't seem to work (actually no events seem to work at all). I am able to hook into the windows messages going to the HwndHost, however, I can't seem to find anything of use.

I am trying to be able to drag a node from a tree-view onto an HwndHost that is hosting XNA. I set AllowDrop to true on the HwndHost, but it appears to do nothing. Does anyone know how I can enable to HwndHost to be a target of a drag/drop operation?

Thanks!

Comment: I would look into getting the expression.interactivity dll that allows you to call drag and drop events in your viewmodel. Its one of the easier ways to implement drag and drop with wpf..just google expression interactivity for wpf drag and drop. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem. I already have a full architecture based on AttachedEvents in Wpf and I need to reuse the same architecture for my HwndHost derived class. I have already implemented all OLE drag and drop classes (in c++/cli) to interact with windows drag and drop infrastructure, but I can't raise events to WPF because of the internal DragEventArgs constructor.

Comment: Well, I found a super hacky workaround. If you child the HwndHost to a DockPanel, and set AllowDrop on the DockPanel, you can respond to events there instead of on the HwndHost. The DockPanel must have a Background though. I tried it with other Frames/Controls, and only the DockPanel seemed to work.

Comment: Yes, I tried that with a border but that only works for Drag and Drop. I would like to enable all events (mousemove, clicks etc). By now I'm using the workaround, but I would like the non workaround way

Comment: True, I had to hook into the windows message pump to get mouse events and whatnot (then try to translate them to the same style of WPF events). I think the main problem is that as soon as you get child elements on the HwndHost, you won't be able to get any info at all. Thanks for putting a bounty on it by the way.

Comment: have a look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gong-wpf-dragdrop

Answer (score 0):

Is this behavior only when running under the debugger?

Are you running Visual Studio as administrator?

If so I recently ran into this problem.  Try it without debugging, if that works you'll need to run the app then attach to it to debug the drag and drop code.

It's a security feature in Windows :/